# Resizing array problem

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

I need some help with this problem.

Suppose you have an array of  size $n$ where $n = 4^i$ for some $i \geq 0$,  with initially $n$ elements in it. Let $m$ be the current number of elements in the array at any point in time.

Then you keep deleting an element from the array one at a time. But right after every delete, if $\frac{m}{n} \leq \frac{1}{8}$ then we create a new array of size $\frac{n}{4}$ and copy the elements (1 copy operation per element) from the previous array to this new array and this is the array that we now delete from (we then ignore the old array and $n$ is now the size of this new array).

What is the total number of copy operations given an array of size $n$?

Thanks.

Comment: So we delete $\frac{7}{8}$ of the elements yet we copy a quarter over?  How does that work?  Also you define two things as the 'current' number of elements.  Do you mean $n$ is how many elements you start with?

Comment: n is the number of elements you start with, then as you delete elements, the number of elements change, so I just set m to be the current number at any time.

Comment: And how are we copying over $n/4$ elements when $m/n$ is less than an eighth?

Comment: When m/n is <= 1/8, then you copy whats left of the elements to a new array of size n/4.

Comment: So when we start deleting from the new array, are we then deleting elements which don't exist in it?

Comment: No, so when you create a new array, you copy the elements from the previous array to this new array, then just ignore the old array. Then start deleting from this new array.

Comment: Yes but the array has size $n/4$ but we only have $n/8$ elements.  Where do we start deleting from?

Comment: Here is a trace (I think this is right...):
size = 1024, n = m = 1024
...delete...create new array...
size = 256, m = 128
...delete...create new array...
size = 64, m = 32
...delete...create new array...
size = 16, m = 8
...delete...create new array...
size = 4, m = 2
...delete...create new array...
size = 1, m = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your trace, you start with $4^i$ elements, you then copy across $4^i / 8$, then you copy across $4^i / 64$, etc.  Essentially you want to find $2 + 8 + 32 + ... + 4^{i}/8$.  This is just the geometric series $$2 (1 + 4 + ... + 4^{i-2}) = 2(4^{i-1} - 1)/3$$

So in the case of $n=1024$ initially, $i = 5$, and the number of copy operations is:
$$ \frac{2}{3} (4^4 - 1) = 170$$

Comment: How do you write the function in terms of n?

Comment: $n = 4^i$ so replace $i$ by $\log_4 n = \frac{\log_2 n}{2}$